# Post Request Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, rest, post, django-rest-framework

This is my views.py

```
from rest_framework import generics, permissions
from .models import Survey,Response
from .serialize import SurveySerializer,ResponseSerializer,SurveySerializerQuestion
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view

class SurveyList(generics.ListAPIView):
    model = Survey
    serializer_class = SurveySerializerQuestion

    def get_queryset(self):

        return Survey.objects.all()


class SurveyListByID(generics.ListAPIView):
    model = Survey
    serializer_class = SurveySerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        survey_id = self.kwargs['survey_id']
        return Survey.objects.filter(survey_id = survey_id)


class ResponseList(generics.ListAPIView):

    model = Response
    serializer_class = ResponseSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        survey_id = self.kwargs['survey_id']
        return Response.objects.filter(survey_id = survey_id)
```

This is my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from views import SurveyList,SurveyListByID,ResponseList
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^surveys/$', SurveyList.as_view(),name ='survey-list') ,
url(r'^surveys/(?P<survey_id>[0-9]+)/$', SurveyListByID.as_view(),name ='survey-list-by-id'), 
url(r'^response/(?P<survey_id>[0-9]+)/$', ResponseList.as_view(),name ='response-list'), 
)
```

This is serialize.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Employee,Survey,EmployeeSurvey,Response

class SurveySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Survey
        fields = ('survey_id', 'question', 'choice1','choice2')


class SurveySerializerQuestion(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Survey
        fields = ('survey_id', 'question')

class ResponseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Response
        fields = ('id','survey_id','choice1_count','choice2_count')
```

finally this is models.py

```
import re
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def alphanumeric_test(val):
    if not re.match('^[0-9a-zA-Z]*$', val):
        raise ValidationError('Only alphanumeric characters are allowed.')

def alphabetic_test(val):
    if not re.match('^[a-zA-Z]*$', val):
        raise ValidationError('Please enter alphabetic value.')

class Survey(models.Model):
    survey_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    question = models.CharField(max_length = 300)
    choice1 = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    choice2 = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    def __unicode__(self):              
        return u'%s %s %s' % (self.question,self.choice1,self.choice2)


class Response(models.Model):
        survey_id = models.ForeignKey(Survey, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
        choice1_count = models.IntegerField()
        choice2_count = models.IntegerField()
        def __unicode__(self):              
    return u'%s %s %s' % (self.survey_id,self.choice1_count,self.choice2_count)
```

Now how do I write a POST request in Django Rest without UI and using the Django Rest Browser.
I want to do a POST request to capture the choice in the survey using a url like I did for get.Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In views.py add a new class like this:

```
class SurveyAPIView(APIView):

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = SurveySerializer(request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            instance = serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

and in urls.py add a new line like:

```
url(r'^create-survey/$', SurveyAPIView.as_view(),name ='create-survey') ,
```

Comment: Thanks! But how to record just the choice in url? Eg Are you Happy? Yes or No. I want to capture just Yes or No and increment the count in Response table columns matched against survey_id

Comment: Is the idea that 'choice1' might be 'Yes' and 'choice2' could be 'No' and then the counts in the Response table would be counts of Yes responses (stored in Response. choice1_count ) and counts of No responses (stored in choice2_count)?  After the serializer is validated in the above example you can get the response values as serializer.data['choice1'] and serializer.data['choice2'].

Comment: The choice can be anything.for  Eg which beverage do you like? Tea Coffee

Comment: Ok.  So is accessing the choice response via serializer.data['choice1'] (and so on) what you were looking for to record the choice in the Response table?